# How to derive the limit of ratio between VaR and CVaR?

Tags: value-at-risk, cvar

I know if $X \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, then $VaR_{\alpha}(X) =\mu + \sigma\Phi^{-1}(\alpha)$ and $CVaR_{\alpha}(X) = \mu + \sigma \frac{\phi(\Phi^{-1}(\alpha))}{1-\alpha}$

But how to evaluate $\lim_{\alpha \to 1}\frac{VaR_{\alpha}(X)}{CVaR_{\alpha}(X)}$?

Comment: The Mills Ratio may be useful here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mills_ratio

Comment: This is basically a calculus question: \begin{align*}
\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow 1} \frac{VaR_{\alpha}}{cVaR_{\alpha}} &= \lim_{\alpha\rightarrow 1}\frac{\mu+\sigma\Phi^{-1}(\alpha)}{\mu + \sigma \frac{\phi(\Phi^{-1}(\alpha))}{1-\alpha}}\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\mu+\sigma x}{\mu + \sigma \frac{\phi(x)}{1-\Phi(x)}}.
\end{align*}